# count and redirect url in javascript like as whatsapp locker

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

Please help me to solve this logic: When a user in mobile device and after clicking on button then whatsapp is open with my site URL then user share this URL with his friends. I want to perform this action 2 times or more after action completed user is redirected to another website.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Share Content on WhatsApp Using jQuery Demo - <MyCodingTricks/></title>
    <style>
    body{background-color:#49C34F}
    .mct_whatsapp_btn {
        background: #11A518;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 6px 9px 6px 28px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        position: relative;
        transition: ease-in all 0.3s;
        moz-transition: ease-in all 0.3s;
        -o-transition:ease-in all 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition: ease-in all 0.3s;
        text-decoration: none;
        box-shadow: inset 3px 1px 1px rgba(17, 165, 24, 0.25);
        border: 1px solid #028408;
    }

    .mct_whatsapp_btn:before {
        content: '';
        background: url(http://mycodingtricks.com/demo/javascript/how-to-share-content-on-whatsapp-using-jquery/whatsapp.png);
        position:absolute;
        top: 6px;
        left: 7px;
        width:16px;
        transition: ease-in all 0.3s;
        moz-transition: ease-in all 0.3s;
        -o-transition:ease-in all 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition: ease-in all 0.3s;
        height:16px;
    }

    .mct_whatsapp_btn:hover {
        background: #028408;
        text-decoration: none;
        color:white;
        border: 1px solid #11A518;
        box-shadow: inset 3px 1px 1px rgba(2, 132, 8, 0.25);
    }

    .mct_whatsapp_btn:hover:before {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 well">

        <a href="#" data-text="2 Ways to Count Facebook Likes, Shares and Comments using PHP" data-link="http://mycodingtricks.com/php/2-ways-to-count-facebook-likes-shares-and-comments-using-php/" class="mct_whatsapp_btn">Share</a>

       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var click=0;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on("click", '.mct_whatsapp_btn', function() {
         click += 1;
         alert("you clicks"+click+"times" );
        if (click == 2) {
        window.location.href = www.google.com;
        }
        else{
             if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                var text = $(this).attr("data-text");
                var url = $(this).attr("data-link");
                var message = encodeURIComponent(text) + " - " + encodeURIComponent(url);
                var whatsapp_url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + message;
                window.location.href = whatsapp_url;
            } else {
                alert("Please use an Mobile Device to Share this Article");
            }
        }


        });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless so the script is evaluated at each page load. Since you redirect to a new page, your first page no longer know how many times the user has clicked.

You can use something like [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the number of clicks in the browser's storage.

Here is a simple example:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('#clicks');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var STORAGE_ID = 'click-count';

// Get count on page load
var clickCount = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_ID) || 0;
element.textContent = clickCount;

// increment count each button click
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var clickCount = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_ID) || 0;
  clickCount++;
  localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_ID, clickCount);
  element.textContent = clickCount;
  if (clickCount === 1) {
     // you clicked once
  } else if (clickCount === 2) {
     window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Click Me Many Times</button>
<div>
  Clicks: <span id="clicks">0</span>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) to save the state.